# R Shiny - Vertically aligning a label and input in a horizontal form

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I am trying to vertically align an input and its label in a horizontal form. I'm not sure if it's possible to vertically align inline divs of different heights though.

The code below gives me the following:

[image]

I would like the labels to sit inline with the inputs.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- fluidPage(

  column(width = 8, 

    tabBox(width = 12, 

      tabPanel(
        'Items', 

        fluidRow(
          style = 'margin:2px',

          wellPanel(
              tags$form(class = 'form-horizontal',
                tags$b('Filter items'),

                tags$div(
                  class = 'form-group',

                  tags$label(class = "col-sm-3 control-label", `for` = 'type', "By type:"), 
                  column(
                    width = 9, 
                    pickerInput(
                      inputId = 'type', label = '', 
                      choices = character(0), 
                      multiple = T
                    ))), 

                tags$div(
                  class = 'form-group',

                  tags$label(class = "col-sm-3 control-label", `for` = 'name', "By name:"), 
                  column(
                    width = 9, 
                    searchInput(
                      inputId = 'name', label = '',
                      placeholder = "Search by name",
                      btnSearch = icon("search"),
                      btnReset = icon("remove")
                    ))
                  )
                )
              )
          )
      )
    )
  ) #/column 8
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I have tried besides `column(width = 3, ...)`:

- flex: `tags$div(class = 'form-group', style = 'display:flex;
  align-items:center;', ...)`
- position: `tags$div(class = 'form-group', style = 'display:table; position:absolute;', tags$label(class = "col-sm-3 control-label", style = 'display;table-cell; vertical-align:middle;', ...), ...)`.

I'm not well-versed in HTML so it's taking a lot of guesswork. What would be the best way to achieve the desired result? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe just arrange the tab panel with multiple fluid rows and
inside these arrange the things you like with columns.

```
#
#
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tabBox(
        tabPanel(title = "Items",
                 wellPanel(
                     fluidRow(column(width = 12,"Filter Items")),
                     br(),
                     fluidRow(
                         column(width = 3,"By Type: "),
                         column(width = 9,
                                pickerInput(inputId = "choices.type",
                                            choices = character(0),
                                            multiple = TRUE))
                            ),
                     fluidRow(
                         column(width = 3,"By Name: "),
                         column(width = 9,
                                searchInput(inputId = "seach.name",
                                            placeholder = "Search",
                                            btnSearch = icon("search"),
                                            btnReset =  icon("remove")))
                            )
                        )

                )
        )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks Andreé, I did think of using `column()` but wanted to see if it was possible with `form-horizontal` as well. With the latter, I had to add a line break inside the label tag to make it line up with the input but that seemed like a hacky solution so I thought to ask here.